# Parsing empty XML elements in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

PHP newbie here. I'm parsing a long XML file, setting each tag to a variable. If the element's tag is empty, I want to assign it the value "N/A"

I'm wondering if there's a more concise way to do this than my current approach:

```
$elements = array()

$propertyOwner = $report->PropertyProfile->PrimaryOwnerName[0];
array[] = $propertyOwner;
$propertyAddress = $report->PropertyProfile->SiteAddress[0];
array[] = $propertyAddress;
...
for($i=0; $i<count($elements); $i++) {
    if (array[i] === '') {
        array[i] = 'N/A');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the code was written originally (without `$`s in front of each variable) you'd probably be getting errors all day. Hope this helps simplify:

```
$array[] = '';
$elements = array();
$propertyOwner = $report->PropertyProfile->PrimaryOwnerName[0];
$elements[] = $propertyOwner;
$propertyAddress = $report->PropertyProfile->SiteAddress[0];
$elements[] = $propertyAddress;
//...
//         IF                  THEN        ELSE
$array[] = !empty($elements) ? $elements : 'N/A';
```